# C++ operator overloading method

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm working through some home work and having problems with how to form my method signature for overloading a member of a class.

My header file

```
class MyInt
{
    int internalInt;
public:
    MyInt::MyInt(int i);
    const MyInt operator+(const MyInt& mi);
    const MyInt& operator++();
};
```

My code file

```
MyInt::MyInt(int i)
{
    internalInt = i;
}

const MyInt MyInt::operator+(const MyInt& mi)
{
    cout << "Inside the operator+\n";
    mi.print(cout);
    return MyInt(internalInt + mi.internalInt);
}

const MyInt& MyInt::operator++()
{
    cout << "Inside the operator++\n";
    internalInt++;
    return this; //Line 42
}
```

When I try to compile the code I'm getting an error that says

```
ex4.cpp:42: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘const MyInt&’ 
from expression of type ‘MyInt* const’
```

I'm having problems understanding how to get this working and have tried a few method signatures. In my text book they are in lining all the overloads but I was hoping to figure out what I'm doing wrong instead of just going with the flow to get my code to compile.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you point out which line is line 42 in your original source file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try:

```
const MyInt& MyInt::operator++()
{
    cout << "Inside the operator++\n";
    internalInt++;
    return *this;
}
```

You are returning the this pointer, not the reference, you need to dereference it.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, in `operator++()`, write `return *this;` instead of `return this;`. Also remove the const!

-

```
 const MyInt operator+(const MyInt& mi);
```

Second, Make it const-function, as

```
 const MyInt MyInt::operator+(const MyInt& mi) const // <--- note this!
```

This is const-function. Without it, you would not be able to add const objects of MyInt.

After you write `const` on the right most side, you can write this:

```
const MyInt m1(10);
MyInt m2(20);
MyInt m3 = m1 + m2 ; //m1 is const, so it can call ONLY const-function
```

Comment: So basically I should not return a const since the return object should be mutable (makes sense) however I should accept a const argument since we aren't changing the value in the method right?

Comment: @Mike: Exactly. And writing `const` on the right most makes the `this` pointer const.

Comment: The return object really ought not be mutable, as primitive type temporaries are not mutable. Consider `a = (b + c) = d;`  This would not be allowed for `int`, but would be allowed for `MyInt` unless the return value from `operator+` is `const`.